# How do I add user values into a 2D array

Tags: java

Given the 2d array:

```
double[][] table;
table = new double[4][5];
```

I know how to print the array with 20 0's using:

```
for (int ii = 0 ; ii < table.length ; ii++)
{
    for (int jj = 0 ; jj < table[0].length ; jj++)
    {
      System.out.print(table[ii][jj] + "\t");
    }
  System.out.println("");
}
```

I would like to ask the user to input "1,2,3" where 1 is the row, 2 is the column and 3 is the value that goes in the cell. Please help me how to do this using the string split method. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String numString = "1,2,3";

String[] splitString = numString.split(",");

int num1 = Integer.parseInt(splitString[0]);
int num2 = Integer.parseInt(splitString[1]);
int num3 = Integer.parseInt(splitString[3]); 

table = new double[4][5];
table[num1][num2] = num3;
```

Answer (score 0):

That's easy if you go step by step:

- use `Scanner` class on `System.in` to read a line through `nextLine()`
- split the `String` according to the given delimiter (`","`)
- check if amount of tokens is correct
- convert each token to an `int` through `Integer.parseInt(..)`
- set the correct value through `table[x][y] = v`